# IIS host Multiple applications

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to setup multiple applications within IIS, single server. I want all to use port 80 and the server has only one IP address.
I have created two application (site1 and site2) within IIS and modified the 'Host name' under bindings on each as follows:
site1.mywebsite.com
site2.mywebsite.com

and kept the IP address and port values to be 'All unassigned' and '80' respectively.

I have "mywebsite.com" through godaddy, and not sure how should I configure dns zone file to take this into effect. Please help....

(My ultimate objective is to have n+1 sites hosted in the same server, so that site1.mysite.com through siten.mysite.com points to their respective application, and every other subdomain points to n+1 th application.

Is this a possibility?)

Thanks in advance,
Anuruddha

Comment: Yes, through IIS you can configure bindings so each hostname points to a different site.  This question would be better suited on serverfault.stackexchange.com, however.

Answer (score 0):

Both `site1.mywebsite.com` and `site2.mywebsite.com` must point to the same IP - one assigned to your server by GoDaddy. So as long as users access the sites by host names you're fine.